# Monotouch Dialog - Reload data list after modifying row detail not updating list when returning

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

When an item is clicked, a details view controller is opened that makes some webservice calls to save back the data if the user clicks save (this works fine).  The issue I have is after saving the data when the user clicks back to go back to the list, the list item (ie if the name was updated) is not updated.  So, perhaps the user changes the name and so the list prior should be updated, I'd like to update the value without having to make another webservice call to repopulate.

I am calling `this.ReloadData()` when the view appears, but this never seems to update the list names.  I've checked `workouts` which is a list of objects, and it has been modified by the detail controller, however the reload data doesn't seem to do anything.

How do I refresh the data in the case that another controller has modified the list of objects.

```
public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
    {
        InvokeOnMainThread (delegate {                      
            this.ReloadData();
        }); // call reload on main thread

                    base.ViewWillAppear (animated);
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        workouts = manager.GetWorkouts(Helpers.User.Auth);
        var sections = new Section();
        var root = new RootElement("Workouts"){sections};
        foreach (var wo in workouts) {
            var tempwo = wo;
            var wodetail = new RootElement(wo.Name, delegate {
                var W = new WorkoutViewModel(tempwo);
                var p = new WorkoutDetailController(W, tempwo);
                return p;
            });
            sections.Add (wodetail);            
        }

        Root = root;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that when you assign the value of an element from a custom object like so:

```
AccountDetailsSection = new Section ("Details"){
            new StringElement ("Code:",  _Account.Code),
            new StringElement ("Name:",  _Account.Name) };
```

You get the desired result but the element loses the pointer back to the property of the object. So if you change the value of the property later for example:

```
_Account.Code = "xxx";
```

Reloading the data doesn't do anything. You should manually update the value like so:

```
(AccountDetailsSection.Elements [0] as StringElement).Value = "xxx";
this.Root.Reload ( AccountDetailsSection, UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade);
```

Hope this Helps.

Comment: Thanks.. I'll give it a try (might be a while before I get back) though I was hoping that there was a solution that would work by just reloading the data set..