# How can I update an existing DialogViewController RadioElement group after navigating away using MonoTouch?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I am looking for ideas as to how I should implement this:

I have an app with a tab bar controller, and off of this come navigation controllers for each "Screen" (which is accessed by its own tab on the tab bar nav at the bottom.

Each screen is then a DialogViewController where I have various elements and items to input and view data with. On one screen the user has a choice of items using a RadioGroup of RadioElements

```
MyRadioElement _customRadioElement = new MyRadioElement (lines [0], lines [5], setRPMElementData); // set profile name and calculated IOPS for custom disk to this custom element
            // Disk Speed Root Element
            _diskspeed = new RootElement ("Disk Speed: ", new RadioGroup (0)){
                new Section ("Disk Speed:"){
                    new MyRadioElement("5400 RPM","5400",setRPMElementData),
                    new MyRadioElement("7200 RPM","7200",setRPMElementData),
                    new MyRadioElement("10K RPM","10K",setRPMElementData),
                    new MyRadioElement("15K RPM","15K",setRPMElementData),
                    new MyRadioElement("SSD","SSD",setRPMElementData),
                    _customRadioElement // this is the MyRadioElement defined above (our custom disk profile)
                }
            };
```

The last element (_customRadioElement) is a RadioElement that is created by loading some info out of a saved disk object. I read the lines of the text file and use this to create my RadioElement. It is originally created by using another Tab on the Tab Bar Controller to access another screen (also a DialogViewController) which allows the user to specify their "custom disk" and save it to disk/file.

My issue is when you are in the app, and want to modify this custom disk, you go to the custom disk editing tab, make the changes, and then flick back to the main tab where the RadioGroup is - however the custom disk RadioElement at the end of the RadioGroup list does not update. (Well the caption does not update, but the actual data behind it does). Even after pressing the back button to go out of the RadioGroup and back into it again. The only way I can get it to update is by killing the app, and restarting - the custom disk object is read in from the file again when the DialogViewController is created and then shows up fine. I tried using ViewWillAppear to create the whole table I need, but the issue with this is that everything is reset each time I flick between tabs, where I only need the custom disk RadioElement or the RadioGroup itself to be updated.

How can dynamically refresh this RadioGroup and it's associated RadioElements whilst still in the app and flicking between tabs?

I have tried using ViewDidAppear however this is on the DialogViewController itself, and doesn't seem to affect the RadioGroup. E.g.

```
public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear (animated);

        Console.WriteLine ("Forcing table reload...");
        LoadDiskInfo(); // Reload disk info from local app storage
        this.ReloadData(); // Force refresh of dialog viewcontroller table data - need to refresh the custom disk RadioElement somehow...
    }
```

Any help would be much much appreciated!

Comment: What about raising an event when your data changes and subscribing to that event either in the appropriate viewcontroller (if a data-change should lead to a completely new element) or the appropriate view (if a data-change should lead to a change in appearance of an existing element)?

Comment: Hi Larry, thanks for the answer. I will look into doing this- I have not done it before (setting up events and subscribing to them) so I'll need to figure that out first for myself and then apply it to this situation. Do you know of any tutorials or samples that show this process? I learn best by viewing an example I find and then applying that to my situation. If not, I'll trawl around some more and see what I can find!

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't really think of any tutorials that go directly to your use-case. Events and subscriptions in C# are quite simple, I'm  confident that you'll be able to find the appropriate resources. If not, SO is always a good place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You may find my answer to this post helpful:
[Monotouch Dialog - Reload data list after modifying row detail not updating list when returning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832163/monotouch-dialog-reload-data-list-after-modifying-row-detail-not-updating-list/15268469#15268469)

Hope this Helps
Vassilis